# How do I become familiar with Python/Django framework if I'm a front-end developer?

Tags: python, django, web, collaboration, frontend

I'm a front-end developer but I need to work with a Python/Django developer on a web project in the summer. I don't necessarily want to learn Django but I want to become competent in learning how to navigate myself around and know the best practices in editing the front-end for a Django project. 
I know HTML/CSS/JS. I have some experience in editing front-end on a RoR framework.

How long should I expect the learning curve to take? Any resources you would recommend?

General advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Learning a new framework is kind of the same as learning how to drive your parents' stick-shift:  there's going to be gears grinding, yelling, and panicking; but given enough time, it'll be second nature.

Comment: Django's template system, which you'll be working with, was designed to be fairly easy to learn. Look at the "for designers" links in [the "template layer" section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/#the-template-layer). The most important document you'll probably want to at least partially read is the [syntax overview](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/templates/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by going through the [templating section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/templates/) of the manual to be familiar with the design language. The rest of the manual is also very light reading, but not necessary for your needs.

Since you have some exposure to rails, you should know that unlike rail's default template engine, django's does not allow Python in the template. This is by design. There are lots of [built-in filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#ref-templates-builtins-filters) and [tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#ref-templates-builtins-tags) that provide most of the logic you would need. Developers can always write custom filters and tags, and some django applications ship with their own tags and filters. For your needs, you just need to know what the built-in ones are and how to apply them.

Unlike ruby, there is no strict concept of "asset pipeline" and built-in javascript libraries. Django's admin site (the CRUD front end) ships with jquery but its namespaced so you won't run into conflicts. Basically, in django - use whatever javascript/front end library tickles your fancy.

I found django's template language to be very easy to understand and you should not have any problems - especially with your familiarity with rails.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best introduction to Python using the Django framework is simply following the Django tutorial found on their website:

[Django Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/)

The key here is to not simply copy-paste and breeze through the tutorial to get to the end product.  Really try to understand each step of the process.  The tutorial covers pretty much all the basics of what you'll want to know.

After that, there are several titles

Answer (score 0):

Best way to learn Django I found was through, **The Django Book** http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/index.html

You can start reading it, specially chapter [three](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter03.html) (views) and [four](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04.html) (templates) will help you figure out how front end is handled in Django.

Comment: Hi, I don't want to learn Django though. I just want to be well-versed in editing the front-end dev of it. Is this impossible? It seems like going through Ch 1-6 would be sufficient for my needs but I'd appreciate your feedback